# How to switch template column in Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that has a template column of a dropdown. How do I switch the template column to use a different control on certain rows?
Here is what I have with my grid

```
function OrderEntryOptions() {
$("#orderEntryOptions").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "Options",
        title:"Options"
    },
    {
        field: "SelectAreas",
        template: '<select class="form-control" ><option>False</option><option>True</option></select>',
    }],
    dataSource: {
        data: [{
            Options: "Show Self Note Column"
        },
        {
            Options: "Ctrl+C, Ctrl-V for Excel Commands"
        },
        {
            Options: "Validation: Show Yellow Alerts when Printing"
        },
        {
            Options: "Default Import/Export Directory"
        },
        {
            Options:"Show Sq. Ft. on screen"
        },
        {
            Options: "Process Global Defaults"
        },
        {
            Options: "Catalog Tree Auto-Expand"
        },
        {
            Options: "Hide Sections column in Globals"
        },
        {
            Options:"First column in blank row to get focus"
        },
        {
            Options: "Search on item name only"
        }
        ]
    }
});
}
```

In my Options column where it says "Default Import/Export Directory", I need to remove the dropdown and use a button instead, then in my Options column where it says "First column in blank row to get focus", I need to change the values in the dropdown from True/False to column names of another grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the template using:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">    
</script>
```

In your grid definition change:

```
template: '<select class="form-control" ><option>False</option><option>True</option></select>'
```

to:

```
 kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()
```

Inside this template you can add conditions, something like:

```
  <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        # if (Options== "Default Import/Export Directory") { #
        <button id="button_id">Button text</button>
        # } else { #
         <select class="form-control" ><option>False</option><option>True</option></select>
        # } #            
    </script>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, the only thing is my kendo grid is being called from an external file

Comment: Once it's working you can pass it as before template: '#if....'  i wrote it down that way for reading purposes

Comment: So the rowTemplate will need to be in the view and the rest in my external file?

Comment: Yes, where you have $("#orderEntryOptions") you can add also the template and it should be visible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean...are you meaning that I can add that <script id="rowTemplate"...> into the function?

Comment: Sorry if cannot make myself clear. There are 2 options:1 leave it with <script> ....</script> in your view file. 2 add it as before template:'if(your condtions)....<select>....'

Comment: I wanted to suggest to make it work with <script></script> because it's much easier to write and debug and once it's working you can copy it to your earlier version the one withtemplate: '<select class="form-control" >......

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I understand. Thanks